# How to select from excel table with left join in access database - EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado

i'm having difficult to create on query with two different database in ADO, i need to make a lot of queries with different sources, for example select from  excel file with left join in access file.

When i use two different excel files like the code below works fine.

```
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim CN As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Open connection
    CN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\ExcelTable.xlsx" & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    SQL = " SELECT * FROM [table1$] t1" _
        & " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM" _
        & " [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\db1.xlsx].table2) t2" _
        & " ON t1.[reftable1] = t2.reftable2"

    rs.Open SQL, CN, adOpenDynamic

    If rs.EOF = False Then


        Do While Not rs.EOF
            debug.print rs("field1")
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop


    End If

    rs.Close
    CN.Close
```

But i need to make this query with left join in the access file and i got the error: "cannot update database or object is read only" when i try to open the record set.

My code:

```
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim CN As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Open connection
    CN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\ExcelTable.xlsx" & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    SQL = " SELECT * FROM [table1$] t1" _
        & " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM" _
        & " [Data Source=C:\db1.accdb].table2) t2" _
        & " ON t1.[reftable1] = t2.reftable2"

    rs.Open SQL, CN, adOpenDynamic

    If rs.EOF = False Then


        Do While Not rs.EOF
            debug.print rs("field1")
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop


    End If

    rs.Close
    CN.Close
```

Comment: Is Table2 a sheet name in first code? Second version code is in one DB and calling another DB and workbook? Tried the first code and does not work. Tried reversing so CN is set for Access and Excel is in the SQL statement. Didn't work either. I can't make either connection string work embedded in SQL statement. I can't find any example that shows a connection string within SQL statement except for pass through query.

Comment: What Access version & Excel version are you using?

Comment: Folowing June7 comment. is [Linking to Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958) acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Excel 12.0 spec from main connection string since that **gets applied to both sources**. Instead open the access database first *without Excel 12.0 spec*

```
CN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=c:\db1.accdb"
```

now specify the extended property of Excel 12.0 **only for the workbook**

```
SQL = " SELECT t1.name, t2.unit FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\ExcelTable.xlsx;].[Table1$] t1" _
    & " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table1) t2" _
    & " ON t1.reftable1 = t2.reftable2"
```

Hope this helps.