# Trying to update Excel-Table through Access-VBA Code. Error: Cannot find database Object "Ware"

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a number of Excel-Files that contain data which I need to combine into one table.

Is it possible and reasonable to do this from within Access VBA code, which I would prefer? Or should I just do it in Excel VBA?

My idea was to iterate through the Excel-Files and use an SQL statement for UPDATE Column WHERE MyCondition, to get the Values I want to the Column I want. Is it possible this way or what would be a suggestion to solving this?

I have tried it this way until now from Access:

```
Sub Execute_UpdateQuery()
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim NumOfRec As Integer
   Dim strPath As String

   strPath = "D:\Sortierliste August_September\Test.xlsx"

   Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

   conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"

   conn.Execute "UPDATE Ware SET Name = 'test'" & _
      " WHERE Name = 'Ackermann'", NumOfRec, adExecuteNoRecords

   Debug.Print NumOfRec & " records were updated."
   conn.Close
   Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

But that results into an error "Cannot find access-database module "Ware". I guess it is because it is just an excel-table and not a database? I thought it can find an excel-file containing the table called Ware and execute an sql query. Any help or suggestions would be great on how to solve this issue.

Greetz

Comment: Does this help? [How to select from excel table with left join in access database - EXCEL VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554597/how-to-select-from-excel-table-with-left-join-in-access-database-excel-vba)

Comment: [How to run a SQL query on an Excel table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798522/how-to-run-a-sql-query-on-an-excel-table)